# Android SD Card Free Space Issue

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I've got this problem...I use a Micromax A110Q with the stick Jelly Bean...FROM the past few weeks(OR Months) I'm having storage issues with my SD card..I find that it's free storage space is zero bytes...I removed many pics and junk such as cache, hpns folder, lost.dir etc...for some time..I'll get free storage for the things I deleted...but..after an hour or so...I find that my free storage is decreasing slowly and gradually it comes to zero bytes..as I mentioned above I've deleted many junk files and used many apps...but no luck!! It will get to zero again..!!! And the stats don't seem to match up in the storage section inSYSTEM SETTINGS!!

HELP!!!!

Comment: Have you tried inserting the SD card into a card reader and checking the disk space on a PC?

Comment: Yup! I did..but same storage status on the PC as well..I connected it the PC using the USB cord...I think probably there are hidden junk files which i m having trouble to locate...but I've identified some junk files and folders like HPNS, lost.dir, .temp files etc...and I meant *stock Jelly Bean in the first few lines

Comment: And I also use my home WiFi a lot...maybe any app is downloading data and buffing up my card...but the apps are mostly in my internal storage :/... Now I can't take pics! :'(

Comment: Try using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to see what takes up the storage space. If you can't make sense of the output, screenshots will help.

Comment: Hey! Thanks buddy...!! (Y) Your first suggestion to connect to my PC didn't work at first but today ...it worked!! Yess !! And even my phone is showing the storage stats correctly now...3.75 GiBs free!!